# Xamarin Forms Maps with Prism - Navigation issue when using Google maps

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

Everything works fine until i add Xamarin.Forms.Maps xaml tag to the view. My Application views work flow is as follows MainPage.Xaml --> LocationView.Xaml. MainPage has a button , i use delegate command to navigate to LocationView with the help of navigationservice.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
          prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True" 
         x:Class="TruckGPS.Views.LocationViewPage" xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.Maps;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Maps">

<StackLayout VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" Padding="30">

<maps:Map WidthRequest="320" HeightRequest="200"
    x:Name="MyMap"
    IsShowingUser="true"
    MapType="Hybrid"/>
```

LocationViewPage has corresponding LocationViewPageViewModel.

When i click the button on MainPage ViewModel i invoke the Delegate command which works fine without the maps. It stops at the breakpoint on delegate method when clicked but never navigates.

MainPage ViewModel Code:

```
public MainPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
    {
        _navigationService = navigationService;
        ShowMapCommand = new DelegateCommand(ShowMap);
    }

private void ShowMap()
    {
        _navigationService.NavigateAsync("LocationViewPage");

    }
```

Comment: So if you comment out the map control it navigates?

Comment: Yes it navigates and works fine.

Comment: Then it's a problem with the map

Comment: Sure, Will check that out. Right now focusing on other modules so once i'm back to map implementation shall post the outcome. Thanks for the quick response.